# Excel 2007 Text to Date

Tags: excel-2007

I need to change this in excel from Text to Date format and I want it to change from this:

```
Sep 30, 1985 12:00 AM
```

to this:

```
30/09/1985
```

I played around but I think I'm wasting a lot of time and hopefully you can assist me please, I would really appreciate it. I tried this:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),12)
```

and I get this:

```
Sep 30 1985
```

I was trying to break it down and then in the end figure out a way of converting from text to Date but I'm getting nowhere. Please advise if there is a way.

Kind regards
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that:
[image]

The thing is that it's a bit complicated. Here you get date and then you can change format.

Comment: You're a genius! nice one!! Thanks man!! :-)   I would not have figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom format to pick the format you like
[image]

Just ensure the format is date and it works, updated the screenshot as per your request
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't work buddy. Please actually put in one of your cells in excel 'Sep 30, 1985 12:00 AM' and see if your answer works based on what you just told me. Please also note that it's in text format and you need to change it to a Date format.

Comment: No sorry it doesn't work. I'm not really a newbie at excel, so I know about the date format and custom settings. Do you perhaps know an excel formula that solves the problem? Is it possible to expand on my formula or is there another/easier formula?

Comment: http://1drv.ms/YGIcxX

There is copy of my excel file. You can copy paste your date anywhere in the A column. I don't think its that complicated that it needs a complex formula for this problem.

Comment: You see where you have typed out 1985-09-30 12:00:00 AM in cell A2. Now we need an excel formula in cell A3 that brings back 30/09/1985. I have thousands of rows of data. I can't manually type out each date. If you type in cell B3 for example  ISTEXT(A2) it should bring back TRUE. If you try and use custom format for cell A2 to DATE dd/mm/yyyy, nothing will happen.

Comment: I didn't change the custom format for A2 to show you. the exact same was copied on A1.

It has to be version of excel that. It worked like a charm for me. You can test it on online editor at http://1drv.ms/YGIcxX

Comment: Which version of excel are you using though? 2007?

Comment: Am using Excel 2011 for Mac

Comment: This is for excel 2007.